# using Properties.Settings for application settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, settings

I use the built-in settings provided by Visual Studio to store simple application settings. Until now, I've accessed this in my application by using the convention:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting
```

And then call methods like `Save` by using:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save()
```

However, someone recently told me that it is more correct to access the properties by creating a member variable like this:

```
private Properties.Settings settings = new Properties.Settings()
```

And then using the member `settings` to access properties and methods like:

```
settings.MySetting
settings.Save()
```

I vaguely recall that they justified this by describing differences in the way the settings are stored in the user's area.

Can anyone confirm or give further details on the differences? Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Settings.Default` is initialized as follows:

```
private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));
```

So it's almost the same as manually creating an instance of `Settings`, except that the one provided by `Settings.Default` is a synchronized instance. I can't see any good reason to create an instance of `Settings` manually...

Answer (score 12):

This wasted a lot of my time.

```
[MyAppNameSpace].Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Not sure when you can drop the namespace as above but in wpf in the app.xaml.cs code I needed to specify the namespace to get it to compile.

Comment: Thank you thank you! This saved me so much time! Funny how I'm the first one that this has helped after 2.5 years! This worked in app.xaml.cs

Comment: Saved me, too! It worked without the namespace until I moved it to App.xaml.cs, then got "field initializer cannot reference non-static field". Looks like there is a `Properties` member on the `Application` class that it was ambiguous with.